# Getting NoReverseMatch when trying to redirect to another view

Tags: django

Getting error `Reverse for 'view_part' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'part_id': u'54'}' not found`.

URLS.PY

```
url(r'^(\d+)/(\d+)/convert/$', 'store.views.changetool', name = "convert"),
url(r'^(\d+)/view_part/$','store.views.view_part',name="view_part"),
```

VIEWS.PY (`changetool`)

```
def changetool (request, id, unipart=None):
    part = Part.objects.get(id=id)
    file = str (part.content)
    newfile = FormatConversion.ConvertToNew(file)
    return redirect('view_part', part_id = unipart)
```

VIEWS.PY (`view_part`)

```
def view_part(request, part_id, newfile = None):
...
```

Comment: I think that you want to reverse the 'convert', not the 'view_part'. where are you calling somthing like reverse("view_part")?

Comment: I'm not doing a reverse at all -- I think it's the line `return redirect` causing the issue... My goal is simply to redirect to the `view_part` view so that it renders the page it redirects to with a new added variable called `newfile`. But first I wanted to test that it redirects properly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `return redirect('view_part', part_id = unipart)` must be `return redirect('view_part', unipart)`

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect):

> By passing the name of a view and optionally some positional or keyword arguments; the URL will be reverse resolved using the reverse() method:

**EDIT**

Ok. 
On the [reverse()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) function, you have to pass positional arguments (`reverse('some_ulr_name', args=[1945]`) in 'args' kwarg, o keyword arguments (`reverse('some_url_view', kwargs={'year': 1945})`) in 'kwargs' kwarg, because you can use some another kwargs that yo don't want send to url.

But, when you use [redirec()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect), it'll send all args and kwargs to reverse method.

Some example:

```
redirect("view_part", unipart) 
# Will do a 
HttpResponseRedirect( reverse("view_part", args=[unipart]) )

#and a 
redirect("view_part", part_id=unipart)
#will do a
HttpResponseRedirect( reverse("view_part", kwargs={'part_id':unipart}) )
```

the last option fails because your url hasn't a name, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) to add a name to url params

Comment: Still getting `Reverse for 'view_part' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'args': [u'54']}' not found.`

Comment: Here's what I did -- `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("store.views.view_part",args=(unipart,)))` ... this seems to work. Do you know the difference?

Comment: Yes, I know why this works, but, please, tell me if me code works. That is what is shortcut for

Comment: Thanks! It did work surprisingly! (I say surprisingly because I could have sworn I tried this earlier). Can you briefly just explain the difference between the two??

Comment: When I add newfile it is giving me the error again -- the line I have is `return redirect('view_part', unipart, newfile)`. Do you know why?

Comment: Oh I see. Is there a way I can pass the `newfile` to the view without changing the URL?

Comment: I think there is no way, because you are trying to pass a object, while it is especting a number or string.